# android find specific tag value and replace with resource values

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to display some html text in a textview using Html.fromhtml, something like :

```
<font color=royalblue>hello</font> a royalblue color ...
```

royalblue is defined in the android resource file, and there are many other colors

```
<color name="royalblue">#A0B4F0</color> a royalblue color ...
```

I want to find  all the color=xxx and replace it to color=the corresponding values in the color resource file

```
<font color="#A0B4F0">hello</font>
```

so `Html.fromhtml()` can correctly handle the font tag.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
String tv = textview.getText();
tv = tv.replace("royalblue", "#A0B4F0");

textview.setText(tv);
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is coming from a String.. not a textview.. but the same rules apply.

Comment: i only want to replace the "royalblue" in the font tag